# Gridster Portrait relayout

Tags: angular, gridster, angular-gridster2

I'm using angular-gridster2 to display a grid, I'd like it to shrink the number of columns and attempt a best fit relayout when the user rotates screen. I can update maxCols and reduce the size of widgets but it doesn't seem to respond, is this not a common use for the library? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Welcome @Davvvy on Stackoverflow, It would be really helpful if you attached your code snippet with your question. for more help please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the resize event where you need it.

```
this.options.api.resize()
```

I hope it is helpful to you.